# Convergence and regularization in linear regression classifier

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-optimization, linear-regression

I am trying to implement a binary classifier using logistic regression for data drawn from 2 point sets (classes y (-1, 1)). As seen below, we can use the parameter `a` to prevent overfitting.

[image: target_function]

Now I am not sure, how to choose the "good" value for a. 
Another thing I am not sure about is how to choose a "good" convergence criterion for this sort of problem.

Comment: Is this not more of a question for Cross-Validated?

Comment: @Natecat linear regression is technically machine learning, but at its most basic level I would say

Comment: There's no hard rule for determining convergence and regularization parameter. You can split your dataset into 3 parts: train, validation, test. You can train on training data with various values of a and for different numbers of iterations. Then you can predict on the validation set to see how well your classifier does on new data. This gives a hint as to if you overfit/underfit. Once you get good results on the validation set, predict on the test set to get a "true" metric of how good your classifier is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Value of 'a'**

Choosing "good" things is a sort of meta-regression: pick any value for **a** that seems reasonable.  Run the regression.  Try again with **a** values larger and smaller by a factor of 3.  If either works better than the original, try another factor of 3 in that direction -- but round it from 9x to 10x for readability.

You get the idea ... play with it until you get in the right range.  Unless you're *really* trying to optimize the result, you probably won't need to narrow it down much closer than that factor of 3.

**Data Set Partition**

ML folks have spent a lot of words analysing the best split.  The optimal split depends very much on your data space.  As a global heuristic, use half or a bit more for training; of the rest, no more than half should be used for testing, the rest for validation.  For instance, 50:20:30 is a viable approximation for train:test:validate.

Again, you get to play with this somewhat ... except that any *true* test of the error rate would be entirely new data.

**Convergence**

This depends very much on the characteristics of your empirical error space near the best solution, as well as near local regions of low gradient.

The first consideration is to choose an error function that is likely to be convex and have no flattish regions.  The second is to get some feeling for the magnitude of the gradient in the region of a desired solution (normalizing your data will help with this); use this to help choose the convergence radius; you might want to play with that 3x scaling here, too.  The final one is to play with the learning rate, so that it's scaled to the normalized data.

Does any of this help?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am still not sure which orders of magnitude to try... Could it be 1 to 1000? 10^-3 to 1? Is 10^-6 to 10^-3 more realistic? There seem to be way too many options to extensively try.

Comment: Again, that depends on your data.  I've generally found that starting in the range of 10^-3 of a mean data value works well enough.  Also, use learning rate decay if your framework supports it: reduce **a** by, say, 4% every 1000 iterations.  It helps to have a larger learning rate at the start, smaller as you converge.